# Laravel GET Method not sending raw JSON in Server

Tags: laravel, postman

Working with REST API's in Laravel. Can't send raw json request in body using GET method, it returns null values in my server environment. But in local server works fine. Refer the attached images. And my controller code was,

```
public function slots(Request $request)
{   //return $request->all();
    $consult_rule = TRUE;

    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/kolkata');
    $current_time = date('H:i:s');

    $curr_date = date('Y-m-d');

    // $appoint_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->appoint_date)->format('Y-m-d');

    // $appoint_date_format = strtotime($appoint_date);
    // $appoint_day = date('l', $appoint_date_format);

    $date = $request->appoint_date;

    $doctor_id = $request->doctor_id;

    $appoint_for = $request->appoint_for;



    return $this->sendResponse(['doctor_id' => $doctor_id,'appoint_date' => $date,'appoint_for' => $appoint_for], 'Data retrieved successfully.');
}
```

And the images,

For Local server works fine
[Localhost response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XwJQ.png)

For Server works fine with Key Parameters
[Server response with key parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHO7R.png)

For Server return null values with raw JSON parameters
[response with raw JSON parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao0XK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a GET route, it expects parameters in URL.
For POST request, you need to define a separate Route and function which will take parameters in body.

EDIT: you can't send parameters in body when using GET HTTP method.

Refer:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#required-parameters

Comment: But in localhost(xampp) it works, with parameters in GET body request, kindly explain how this works.

Comment: is php and laravel versions similar on XAMPP and server?